# I need to extract values using the LENGTH function from 2 different tables but use only 1 query

Tags: mysql, sql, function, rows

I have 2 very basic tables, each with only 1 column. Table "meats" lists 8 or 9 different types of meats and the table "cheeses" lists a variety of cheeses.

I know how to extract all values that contain more than 5 characters from either table (example: `SELECT * from cheeses WHERE LENGTH(c_item) > 5;`) which returns any cheese name with more than 5 characters in the name.

But when I try to join both like such:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    meats
JOIN
    cheeses
WHERE LENGTH(m_item) OR LENGTH(c_item) > 5;
```

not only do I get a Cartesian result, BUT ALL ITEMS ARE LISTED regardless of the number of characters in their names.

The school assignment is to create a query that pulls only the meat and cheeses names with 5 (or more) characters AND do it in a single query!

I have tried various JOINS, UNIONS, Syntax layouts (e.g. including using the WHERE keyword prior to each function, swapping AND for OR, etc.

I need this:

```
SELECT * from cheeses WHERE LENGTH(c_item) > 5;
```

and this:

```
SELECT * from meats WHERE LENGTH(m_item) > 5;
```

combined into one statement.

Comment: Show us your UNION ALL attempt!

Answer (score 1):

With school assignment it is a bit difficult to guess externally the exact requirements, but this sounds like a `union` use case.

However, pls note that `length()` function return the length in **bytes**, not characters. The `char_length()` function is the one that returns the length in term of characters.

```
SELECT * from cheeses WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(c_item) > 5
UNION ALL
SELECT * from meats WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(m_item) > 5;
```

Also, pls note that `union` requires the queries to have exactly the same number of fields and their data types should also be compatible with each other. So, if your `cheeses` and `meats` tables have different number of columns or columns with different data types at the same ordinal position, then you have to adjust the queries accordingly, you cannot simply use `select *`.

Comment: I didn't know that about how the length() returns the length in bytes, not characters. Good to know! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from cheeses WHERE LENGTH(c_item) > 5
UNION ALL
SELECT * from meats WHERE LENGTH(m_item) > 5;
```